# Sorting algorithms with utility functions and iterators

Tags: c++, optimization, algorithm, c++11, sorting

My implementation of insertion, merge, and quick sort, with some utility testing functions. I just wanted to know how I can improve the efficiency and general cleanliness of my code.

(note: I know C++ has partition, but I want to do most of the implementation myself)

In particular, my main algorithms take iterators [first, last], but STL container's `v.begin()` and `v.end()` go 1 over the last element, so I have wrappers that call the main algorithm with `first` and `end - 1`.

How can I restructure this into the main algorithm (if that would be better)?

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// Insert sort O(n^2) time O(1) space
template <typename Iterator>
void ins_sort(Iterator first, Iterator end) {
    for (Iterator cur = first; cur < end; ++cur) {
        auto key = *cur;
        Iterator ins = cur - 1;
        for (; first <= ins && key < *ins; --ins)
            *(ins + 1) = *ins;    // move 1 to right until correct position's found
        *(ins + 1) = key;
    }
}

// Merge sort O(nlogn) time O(n) space
template <typename Iterator>
void merge(Iterator first, Iterator middle, Iterator last) {
    using T = typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
    vector<T> left(first, middle + 1);
    vector<T> right(middle + 1, last + 1);
    left.push_back(0xFFFFFFF); // sentinel
    right.push_back(0xFFFFFFF);
    for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; k <= last - first; ++k) {
        if (left[i] < right[j]) first[k] = left[i++];
        else first[k] = right[j++];
    }
}

template <typename Iterator>
void merge_helper(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    if (first < last) {
        Iterator pivot = first + (last - first)/2;   // half way point rounded down
        merge_helper(first, pivot);
        merge_helper(pivot + 1, last);
        merge(first, pivot, last);
    }
}

template <typename Iterator>
void mer_sort(Iterator first, Iterator end) {
    merge_helper(first, end - 1);
}


// Quick sort O(nlogn) time O(n) space
template <typename Iterator>
void quick_sort(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    if (last - first > 0) {
        auto pivot = *(first + (last - first) / 2); 
        Iterator left {first};
        Iterator right {last};
        while (left <= right) {
            while (*left < pivot) ++left;
            while (pivot < *right) --right;
            if (left <= right) { swap(*left, *right); ++left; --right; }
        }
        quick_sort(first, right);
        quick_sort(left, last);
    }
}
template <typename Iterator>
void qck_sort(Iterator first, Iterator end) {
    quick_sort(first, end - 1);
}
```

**Testing code**

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rand_int {
public:
    Rand_int(int low, int high) : distribution{low, high} {
    }
    int operator()() {
        return distribution(engine);
    }

private:
    default_random_engine engine;
    uniform_int_distribution<> distribution;
};

template <typename T>
void print(vector<T> v) {
    for (auto x : v)
        cout << x << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
}

vector<int> randgen(int max, int num) {
    static Rand_int die{0, max};
    vector<int> res(num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
        res[i] = die();
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- There are few problems with merge:

  There is no guarantee that T can be constructed from an integral constant (how about sorting strings?). Even if it could, `0xFFFFFFF` (BTW, what is this number?) is not necessarily a largest possible value (e.g.T could be 64 bit wide, or 16 bit wide); besides this value may legitimately belong to user data. Bottom line it, using an artificial sentinel is wrong.

  `(left[i] < right[j])` condition breaks merge sort stability (which is very important reason of using merge sort in the first place).

  Calculating pivot as  `first + (last - first)/2` assumes a random access iterator, which rules out merge sorting linked lists (which is a second important reason for merge sort to be used). Take a look at `std::distance` and `std::advance`.
- C++ has partition for a reason: it is very important algorithm of its own. I strongly recommend to factor it out as a function, and call it from `quick_sort`.
- I don't see the reason for `qck_sort` and `mer_sort` to exist.

  Take a look on how all `std::` algorithms operate on *semi-open* ranges. One of the reasons for that is that `last` (in STL sense) serves as a *natural* sentinel. For example, merging may look along the lines of

  ```
  void merge(I first1, I last1, I first2, I last2, O dst)
  {
      while ((first1 < last1) && (first2 < last2)) {
          if (*first1 <= *first2) {
              *dst++ = *first1++;
          } else {
              *dst++ = *first2++;
          }
      }
      while (first1 < last1) *dst++ = *first1++;
      while (first2 < last2) *dst++ = *first2++;
  }
  ```

Comment: Fixed sentinel with merge (I tested with data with largest valid value and it works now); 
I'll take a look at effective partitioning; 
qck_sort and mer_sort just wrap the respective sorts by passing end - 1 for last iterator (can you recommend a better way of dealing with end being 1 after last elem)?

Comment: It is against CR rules to edit the code: it invalidates the review. Consider rolling your changes back. You are welcome to post the new version in a follow-up question.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense; done.
But my previous questions remain regarding end being 1 after last element